# How to run program built on Linux in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows

In linux, i get the outfile `showSigTraceLog` using this command:

`g++ showSigTraceLog.cpp tinyxml2.h tinyxml2.cpp -o showSigTraceLog`

Then i run `showSigTraceLog` succefully in linux, using this command:

`./showSigTraceLog`

But when i copy `showSigTraceLog` to Windows, it cannot run! I meet this error:

> 'showSigTraceLog' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command, operable program or batch file.

How can i run this program `showSigTraceLog` both in Linux and Windows at the same time?

Comment: Where does gdb come into this? It looks like you're compiling a binary on Linux which you then want to run directly on Windows.

Comment: Why not just compile it on Windows?

Comment: Did you try running it on some *NIX emulator on Windows i.e. cygwin ? I am also not sure if that would work either.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478788/running-linux-gcc-compiled-program-under-windows seems to be the same as what you're asking.

Comment: Some linux distributions include mingw crosscompiler that would let you to build windows binary on linux. But linux binary won't run on windows.