# How to create an executable C file for Windows

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, gcc, cygwin

I know this question has been asked several times and I took a look at many of them like

- [Running linux gcc-compiled program under windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478788/running-linux-gcc-compiled-program-under-windows)
- [How can I compile C files into an executable (.exe) file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956597/how-can-i-compile-c-files-into-an-executable-exe-file)

Unfortunately, none of them worked for me.

## My situation

I've installed Ubuntu and Windows on my Notebook.

- Let's say I developed a simple `"Hello,World!"`program using a text editor in c.
- In Ubuntu, I've compiled it using GCC 
  `$ gcc -o hello.out -g -Wall -pedantic hello.c`
- I executed it `'./output.out'`
- And got the result `Hello, World!`

## What I tried

So I kind of cross-developed here. I switched to Windows and kept going.

Now, I try to make it an executable file in order to run it on Windows. I know Windows can't handle `'$ ./output.out'` , alright, let's make it an executable then.

Under Windows, I've

- installed cygwin
- In Cygwin, I compiled it using GCC 
  `$ gcc -o hello.exe -g -Wall -pedantic hello.c`

**Note:** I wrote **hello.exe** instead of **hello.out** or **hello.c**

- In Cygwin, I executed it `'$ ./output.exe'`
- And got the result `Hello, World!`

**Note:** At this point, it even works with my Shell under Windows because I installed Cygwin and set up my PATH etc. This means I can open my command line, go to the directory in which `'hello.exe'` is located and execute it by typing `'> hello.exe'`

I thought that would be it, so I took `hello.exe'` and moved it to another notebook (not my local machine). I tried to execute it but it didn't work.

At first, I got an cygwin1.dll missing message. After fixing it, another error appears.

## What I'm trying to accomplish

To make a long story short:
The reason I wrote so much is that I want to give you a detailed look of my situation.

Basically, I'm trying to create an executable c file, which any Windows User could execute without having any development tools.

In Eclipse and Java, you could simply export your program making it a runnable -jar file. All the User has to do is install the latest Java SE version to get it running.

Additionally, I tried to compile my program in Visual Studio but that didn't work either.

Any suggestions?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: You use a compiler designed for Windows, such as Visual Studio.

Comment: But how do I set up the VS compiler? I read that there is no gcc for Visual Studio

Comment: "how do I set up the VS compiler?" - usually you don't need to, VS is a full IDE. You create a project, add your source files, do any other configuration, and click "run" (or "build").

Comment: That's correct, but the compiler C++ uses seems to differ from which C uses. I'm not an C++ expert, please don't get me wrong,  but if take my code and click "run" to build it, it will cause errors because I implemented a couple of things in a C manner. F.ex. if I use the merge sort and do something like int foo( int p, int r){char arr [ (r-p) +1 ]; } , I'll get an error in C++. I guess I didn't meant it like I wrote it , sorry for that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cygwin gcc produce an executable linked to the cygwin1.dll. So it is not usable without that.

```
gcc  hello.c -o hello-cygwin.exe

$ ldd hello-cygwin.exe
        ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x77bd0000)
        kernel32.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/kernel32.dll (0x77ab0000)
        KERNELBASE.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x7fefdc60000)
        SYSFER.DLL => /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/SYSFER.DLL (0x75650000)
        cygwin1.dll => /usr/bin/cygwin1.dll (0x180040000)
```

If you need a standalone program, a solution is to use the mingw compiler
(it is available on cygwin as cross compiler to windows)

```
$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe hello.c -o hello-mingw64.exe

$ ldd hello-mingw64.exe
        ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x77bd0000)
        kernel32.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/kernel32.dll (0x77ab0000)
        KERNELBASE.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x7fefdc60000)
        SYSFER.DLL => /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/SYSFER.DLL (0x75650000)
        msvcrt.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/msvcrt.dll (0x7fefdf40000)
```

You can move the resulting program on another windows machine that don't have cygwin installed.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was looking for.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `mingw` which is the `gcc` port for windows instead of `gcc` under cygwin. You can get it [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/).

Comment: Dear @Ishay, unfortunately, your solution didn't work. I installed mingw and compiled my program from within the windows command line using gcc. The error remains the same on other machines. If I try to execute it, it will fail

Comment: You accepted the answer that uses mingw what's the difference between that one and what I proposed?

Comment: No offence, he provided an example which for me was easier to understand. Both of you're right.